# Manually abort GPS updating in Android

Tags: android, gps

I receive updates from my GPS in this way:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);
```

In my onLocationChanged(Location loc)-method I want now to abort updating GPS data by specific criteria...

So how can I undo/disable the requestLocationUpdates(...) ?

Nice greetings,
poeschlorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using this method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29

Comment: can I use it like this in the onLocoationChanged()-method?

lm.removeUpdates(this);

Comment: yes as an argument you have to pass the listener object. In your case this should be locationListener as far as i can judge from your code in the question